# Using NodeJs with google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I want to publish my NodeJs server onto app engine, I have already read through the https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world but I couldn't understand it, or what the heck the .YAML has to do with anything. The server will be used for providing HTML files for people going on my website.
 Thanks

Comment: seems this isnt appengine related. its using GCE

Comment: It is App Engine related - it uses Managed VMs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/)

Answer (score 0):

The .yaml files are for configuration of your app for example

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5
  cool_down_period_sec: 60
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

Sets your preferences for how their system will run your code.

See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Required_elements) for what are required values and which are optional.